# Q: External Postfix server for OpenEMM

Tags: postfix

The company i work for needs me to set up an OpenEMM Server to start a Mailing Server System.

We have a Virtual environment where multiple VMs are installed for multiple purposes.

Our goal is to utilize our pre-existing VMs, two of them, which already have, separately, mySQL and Postifix up and running, with a new VM whose task is to Run OpenEMM and OpenEMM only.

(Our aim was to also improve quality of life by avoiding a fresh installation and configuration of Postfix, but that's irrelevant)

I've found out that is it possible and fairly unproblematic to setup a communication between the MySQL server and the OpenEMM Server, as it was documented and covered.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the case for Postfix, whom I haven't found anything for.

So my question is:

By setting up OpenEMM on a fresh machine, is it possible to utilize Postfix from another VM? If so, what should be done and how?

Thank you for reading, if you needed any other informations please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Do you mean using postfix as a relay server?

Comment: If you mean Relay server as per SMTP Server, then yes. But it must (should) be on a different machine than the one with OpenEMM, and I need them to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the OpenEMM documentation, it should just be a case of setting up postfix on the OpenEMM VM to be a satellite system of the external mail server if you are running Ubuntu, use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix` and select 'Internet with smarthost' or 'Satellite system' depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Wouldn't that imply that an installation of Postfix is required on the OpenEMM VM? 
I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: I was going with an installation document I found: http://linuxpitstop.com/install-openemm-on-ubuntu-linux-16-04/ . Unless it's out of date it would be the logical way to do it as if the system is java-based you wouldn't tend to expose java to send mail. You can check on the VM to see what is running on port 25.